# JavaScript - on body load next array element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, arraylist

So I have an html file which calls a javascript function **on body load**. And I want to show an array element one after the other. On first load it should show "**one**" on the next load it should show "**three**" etc. 
But it keep's showing me the first word. Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong and suggest me a solution? Thank you very much in advance!

here is my HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="/style/js/wordSet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<body onload="getWord()">
<div id="character"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and that's my **wordSet.js**

```
    function getWord(){
    var testList = ["one","three","right"]

       var resultSet = testList.shift();
        document.getElementById("character").innerHTML = resultSet;
}
```

Comment: HTML is stateless.  Every time you load the body, the array is reset.  You'll need to use cookies to store a variable that shifts the array

Comment: ...or [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: it's simple, your page and javascript start again after some load. You need to keep the state of the page in some way. You can use cookies or localStorage to reach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close / refresh the page every change you've made is gone. Persist the `testList` array using the `localStorage`:

```
function getWord() {
  var original = ["one", "three", "right"];
  // try to retrieve array from localStorage, return default if it doesn't exist
  var testList = localStorage.testList ? JSON.parse(localStorage.testList) : original ;
  var resultSet = testList.shift();
  // store the array in localStoarge after you change it
  localStorage.testList = JSON.stringify(testList.length ? testList : original );
  document.getElementById("character").innerHTML = resultSet;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now perfectly! But after the 'shift' is over, it just says undefined. Is there a possibility to make it loop, infinitely?

Comment: you are awesome ori, thank you very much! 
I'll need to edit it that the first page should always start with one, and reload should not change the word, but I guess I'll find a way now. 
Thanks again and best wishes to where ever you are!

Comment: Happy to help Faruk :)

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call the function, the array is reinitialized and all the values are put back into it. You could solve that problem by initialising the array *outside* the function.

That would leave you with the second problem, which is that each time you load the page, you restart the program from scratch.

You need to use some persistent storage (such as *localstorage* or a *cookie* to track where in the array you have got to, and then read it when the page loads.